# Programatically queries Channel Number using WinAPI-WlanQueryInterface- Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, wifi

While querying the `WlanQueryInterface` to get the channel number see that the  return value is a large integer like `1820789` etc.. any help?

```
uses nduWlanTypes, nduWlanAPI;

Function GetWifiChannelTest: String;

var

  hClient: THandle;
  dwVersion: DWORD;
  ResultInt: DWORD;
  pInterface: Pndu_WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  i: Integer;
  pInterfaceGuid: TGUID;
  pdwDataSize: DWORD;
  ppData: Tndu_WLAN_INTF_OPCODE;
  pI: Pinteger;
  p: pvoid;

begin

  ResultInt := WlanOpenHandle(1, nil, @dwVersion, @hClient);

  try

    if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error Open CLient' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
      Exit;
    end;

    ResultInt := WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, nil, @pInterface);

    if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error Enum Interfaces ' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
      Exit;
    end;

    for i := 0 to pInterface^.dwNumberOfItems - 1 do
    begin

      pInterfaceGuid := pInterface^.InterfaceInfo[pInterface^.dwIndex]
        .InterfaceGuid;
      ResultInt := WlanQueryInterface(hClient, @pInterfaceGuid,
        wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number, nil, @pdwDataSize, @ppData, nil);

      try

        if (ResultInt = ERROR_SUCCESS) and (pdwDataSize = SizeOf(ppData)) then
        begin
          p := @ppData;
          pI := pvoid(p);
          Result := IntToStr(pI^);
    // the result is 1820789 ,but i need channel number like 10, or 11 etc...
        end;

      except
      end;

    end;

  finally

    WlanCloseHandle(hClient, nil);

  end;

end;
```

Comment: Hard to say. So many pointers all around. Why do you for example pass to the `ppData` parameter pointer to some `Tndu_WLAN_INTF_OPCODE` type variable instead of a pointer to `ULONG` variable? But there's more.. And we cannot even see the API translation.

Comment: Hi Please find the modified code

Comment: modified var  ppData: pndu_WLAN_INTF_OPCODE;

Comment: if (ResultInt = ERROR_SUCCESS) then
        begin
          // Now the result is "wlan_intf_opcode_supported_country_or_region_string_list" ,but i need channel number like 10, or 11 etc...
          Result1 := ppData^; // .wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number;
        end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not enumerating interfaces correctly.  You should not be using `dwIndex` as the index into the `InterfaceInfo[]` array.  Use your loop counter `i` instead.

Also, you are not calling `WlanQueryInterface()` correctly.  `wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number` outputs a `ULONG` value, not a `WLAN_INTF_OPCODE` value.

Also, you are leaking the `WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST` that `WlanEnumInterfaces()` allocates.

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  nduWlanTypes, nduWlanAPI;

Function GetWifiChannelTest: String;
var
  hClient: THandle;
  dwVersion: DWORD;
  ResultInt: DWORD;
  pIntfList: PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  i: DWORD;
  IntfGuid: TGUID;
  dwDataSize: DWORD;
  ChannelNumber: ULONG;
begin
  Result := '';

  ResultInt := WlanOpenHandle(1, nil, @dwVersion, @hClient);
  if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error Open Client: ' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    ResultInt := WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, nil, @pIntfList);
    if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error Enumerating Interfaces: ' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      for i := 0 to pIntfList^.dwNumberOfItems - 1 do
      begin
        IntfGuid := pIntfList^.InterfaceInfo[i].InterfaceGuid;

        ResultInt := WlanQueryInterface(hClient, @IntfGuid, wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number, nil, @dwDataSize, @ChannelNumber, nil);
        if ResultInt = ERROR_SUCCESS then
        begin
          Result := IntToStr(ChannelNumber);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      WlanFreeMemory(pIntfList);
    end;
  finally
    WlanCloseHandle(hClient, nil);
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: after further review, it seems that `wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number` might be outputting a *pointer* to a `ULONG`, so you would need to give it a *pointer to a pointer* to a `ULONG`, and then you can dereference the outputted pointer to get the actual `ULONG`.  Try this:

```
uses
  nduWlanTypes, nduWlanAPI;

Function GetWifiChannelTest: String;
var
  hClient: THandle;
  dwVersion: DWORD;
  ResultInt: DWORD;
  pIntfList: PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;
  i: DWORD;
  IntfGuid: TGUID;
  dwDataSize: DWORD;
  pChannelNumber: PULONG; // <--
begin
  Result := '';

  ResultInt := WlanOpenHandle(1, nil, @dwVersion, @hClient);
  if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error Open Client: ' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    ResultInt := WlanEnumInterfaces(hClient, nil, @pIntfList);
    if ResultInt <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error Enumerating Interfaces: ' + IntToStr(ResultInt));
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      for i := 0 to pIntfList^.dwNumberOfItems - 1 do
      begin
        IntfGuid := pIntfList^.InterfaceInfo[i].InterfaceGuid;

        ResultInt := WlanQueryInterface(hClient, @IntfGuid, wlan_intf_opcode_channel_number, nil, @dwDataSize, @pChannelNumber, nil);
        if ResultInt = ERROR_SUCCESS then
        begin
          Result := IntToStr(pChannelNumber^); // <--
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      WlanFreeMemory(pIntfList);
    end;
  finally
    WlanCloseHandle(hClient, nil);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The result I am getting is 52388696 from the above code, But when I use "netsh wlan show interface" the reulst is 11. Thank you

Comment: pIntfList: PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST; change to  pIntfList: Pndu_WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST;